# Is Microsoft's HyperV VHD file just the image of the hard disk?

Tags: vhd

I would like to know if the Microsoft HyperV VHD file is just an image of the hard disk.

I have a VHD file, and I'm wondering if it contains the entire image of the VM environment. In other words, if I only have the VHD, do I have the actual machine image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is a disk image with corresponding settings. Ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format))